# Python can't find module when started with sudo

Tags: python, module, root, gpio, google-assistant-sdk

I've got a script that uses the Google Assistant Library and has to import some modules from there. I figured out this only works in a Python Virtual Environment, which is really strange. In the same folder I've got a script which uses the GPIO pins and has to use root. They interact with each other, so when I start the GPIO script, the Assistant script is also started. But for some reason the modules in there can't import when the script is started with root. Does anybody know something about this?

Comment: `sudo` runs under a different environment, and your user installed packages aren't available. Sound like your issue? Why don't you activate the virtualenv as root?

Comment: Install all your packages as root, I suppose. Or create a root `venv`.

Comment: @cricket_007 That sounds right, but how can I activate the venv as root?

Comment: @Jan `sudo su` followed by your normal steps to activate a venv.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to activate, just run the script using it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963127/2308683

Comment: @erip activating with sudo doesn't work, just says command not found.

Comment: @cricket_007 I was activating it with "source env/bin/activate" and since I'm not really a python pro I don't know how to do this now :/

Answer (score 15):

not 100% sure but have you tried:

```
sudo -E python myScriptName.py
```

<sub>As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315865/11465149)</sub>

Comment: I have tried. Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 9):

Normally you can active a virtual env and use the interpreter inside the env to run your script. But it is not necessary.

Suppose you have a virtual env under the path /path-to-env/env
the script you want to run example.py is under the path /path-to-script/example.py

you can already run this example.py like

```
sudo /path-to-env/env/bin/python /path-to-script/example.py
```

Comment: This only says sudo: /env/bin/activate: command not found (/env/bin/activate is the path to my venv) Do I need to source this?

Comment: Have you already created a virtual env?
You don't need to activate it, try to run your script like I wrote.

Comment: you mean
/path-to-env/env/bin/python /path-to-script/example.py works but it doesn't work with sudo? basically same command just with/out sudo behave differently?

Comment: With sudo it says command not found. 
Without sudo it says permission denied.

Comment: can you start python interactive mode by using sudo /path-to-env/env/bin/python?

Comment: Starting it with sudo /env/bin/python doesn&#39;t find the RPi GPIO module. Do I have to install modules again for this?

Answer (score 3):

Try to install the module using sudo.

I had the same problem with the module 'reportlab' from python. I realized that I had installed pip (the installer manager for reportlab) without sudo command.

The problem is that the package (pip and reportlab) has been **installed as user and not as root**, so when you try to use sudo, it does not recognize the system path to reportlab because you never installed in the first place, only for the user!

I recommend install pip and module with sudo always:

## For python 2:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
$ sudo python2 get-pip.py
$ sudo pip install google-assistant-library
```

## For python 3 (from [Docs Google assistant library](https://pypi.org/project/google-assistant-library/0.0.3/)):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-venv
$ sudo python3 -m venv env
$ sudo env/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
$ sudo source env/bin/activate
$ sudo python -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-library
```

Hope this helps! Regards!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just installing the python package as sudo and it worked fine. For my case it was `sudo pip3 install findpi` and then executed as `sudo findpi` and worked.