# Why importing with ipython3 or sudo python3 is different?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, sudo

I'm trying to use CircuitPython lib but got some troubles,  I put the files from the [Circuitpython bundle](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Bundle) in `/lib`

- this works

  ```
  $ ipython3
  Python 3.7.3, blabla info
  >> import sys
  >> sys.path.append("/lib/adafruit_hid")
  >> import adafruit_hid
  ```
- this works too

  ```
  $ python3
  Python 3.7.3, same blabla info
  >> import sys
  >> sys.path.append("/lib/adafruit_hid")
  >> import adafruit_hid
  ```
- this doesn't

  ```
  $ sudo python3
  Python 3.7.3, same blabla info
  >> import sys
  >> sys.path.append("/lib/adafruit_hid")
  >> import adafruit_hid
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adafruit_hid'
  ```

And as the script needs to run as `root` I'm stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question is related to the one found here:

https://superuser.com/questions/600349/why-sudo-python-and-python-in-terminal-start-two-different-versions-python/600350

In essence, it's running different versions of python under sudo. This may mean it cannot run the library correctly.

*Edit:*

This may also be related to [Cannot run Python script using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315645/cannot-run-python-script-using-sudo).
(Try running with the -E flag.)

> By default sudo runs commands in different environment.  You can ask
>   sudo to preserve environment with `-E` switch.
>
> ```
> sudo -E python myScriptName.py
> ```
>
> It comes with it's own security risks. So be careful

Comment: I explictly use `python3` to avoid this kind of problem, I guess, and I want to solve it also :D

Comment: @azro, I see that your version may differ in issue from these posts. I will look into this.