# PROBLEM WHILE USING SCAPY (Permission denied)

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, network-programming, scapy

I am trying to make a simple network scanner in python3 which can scan whole devices on LAN. That's when i heard about Scapy. However, whenever i try to run my program, it returns an error
**"PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied"**

**Here's my code:**

```
import scapy.all as scapy


def scan(ip):

  scapy.arping(ip)

scan("192.168.43.1")
```

It would help me a lot if you guys can fix this issue. Thanks for reading.

COMPLETE OUTPUT:

```
          Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "network_scanner.py", line 7, in <module>
         scan("192.168.43.1")
         File "network_scanner.py", line 5, in scan
         scapy.arping(ip)
         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist- 
         packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 628, in arping
         ans, unans = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff") / 
         ARP(pdst=net), verbose=verbose,  # noqa: E501
         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist- 
         packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 503, in srp
         s = conf.L2socket(promisc=promisc, iface=iface,
         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist- 
        packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 467, in __init__
        self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, 
        socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))  # noqa: E501
       File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 231, in __init__
       _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
       PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: Can you edit your question (button at the bottom) to include the complete error message?

Comment: I have added the output

Comment: Did you try `arp-scan` instead of scapy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I Had the same Issue but with *"[Errno 1]"* , what solved it for me was to just use root permissions via `sudo`** *(and `"-E"` to preserve the enviroment)* **like**:

```
sudo -E python myScriptName.py
```

**As mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315865/11465149)  too. |** *⚠️ "It comes with it's own security risks. So be careful".*

Answer (score 1):

I beleive the method `scapy.arping()` opens raw socket. Try running as root user with `sudo`.

Comment: I am using running that program using root terminal in kali linux

Comment: Are you running kali directly or in some VM ?

Comment: I have install kali linux on my android as chroot.

Comment: @FaiyazAhmad please add this to your question. Your environment is important!!

Comment: Being root in chroot environment means nothing, If you are not running the chroot itself from a root environment. Though chroot environment grants permission to open raw socket, your android system wont. You cant solve this problem unless you root your mobile (even i doubt afterwards !)