# YouCompleteMe: compile problem ycm core library not detected. VIM. Linux MInt

Tags: python, linux, vim, linux-mint, youcompleteme

The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with ':YcmRestartServer'). YCM core library not detected; you need to compile YCM before using it.
I tried to compile ycm file using:

https://github.com/todaygood/go_repo/issues/5

[Cannot run Python script using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315645/cannot-run-python-script-using-sudo)

https://vimawesome.com/plugin/youcompleteme#linux-64-bit
and 2 more sources which include same info
but my problem starts when i try to run

> python3 install.py

in terminal

> Error:This script should not be run with sudo.

I have virtualenv, i have cmake, i tried to ran it in my env, i tried using different commands using pip, pip3, python, python3, sudo + <--(,,,,). Of course i tried to do it using root.

Comment: Use YCM's official support channels.

Comment: The current text says `python3 install.py --all`, else *incomplete compilation* → See README.md, "§ Linux 64-bit" https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe → `git clone https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe.git && cd YouCompleteMe/ && git submodule update --init --recursive`

Comment: @KnudLarsen I installed all packages for quick start nothing changed.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Did it nothing changed. now i have 2YouCompleteMe files 1 in bundle and 2nd inside the 1st

Answer (score 1):

**YouCompleteMe** build example with a clean Ubuntu 20.04.3, installed/updated 10 days ago

```
sudo apt install build-essential cmake vim-nox \
python3-dev golang openjdk-11-jdk rust-all npm

    ## in /home/[name]/tmp/
git clone https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe.git
cd YouCompleteMe/
git submodule update --init --recursive

./install.py --all
Generating ycmd build configuration...OK
Compiling ycmd target: ycm_core...OK
Building regex module...OK
Building watchdog module...OK
Installing Omnisharp for C# support...OK
Building gopls for go completion...OK
Setting up Tern for JavaScript completion...OK
Installing rust-analyzer for Rust support...OK
Installing jdt.ls for Java support...OK
Setting up TSserver for TypeScript completion...OK
Setting up Clangd completer...OK
```

(No issues with other OS´s either.)